# Which phrase sounds better( more natural and common for native speaker)." Victim of art"

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, articles, construction

I have doubts about the phrase "Victim of art". Should I change it to "Art victim" or it can be used as it is but may be I miss articles? Or, please, suggest your own version with the same sense.
Thanks.

Comment: Would there be any way that you could supply a little more context - the phrases are just fine as they stand, but without knowing more, it's difficult to make any helpfull suggestions. You can use the"Edit" button to expand your question.

Answer (score 2):

They're both fine (but odd and interesting). It really depends on style and tone. "Art victim" is punchier - it's a good name for a band. :-) "Victim of art", on the other hand, is better as a title for an axiety-filled poem. The *X of Y* phrasing sounds more formal and literary.